# DictWriter with wrong encoding

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I've looked all around the net but I can't seem to get this thing to work.

I'm using **python2.6** to read a csv file **input.csv** and want to output it line-for-line into **output.csv** using **DictReader** and **DictWriter** in python.

I know nothing about the encoding of **input.csv**.
Everything is fine to the EYES when I open **output.csv** but when I run a **diff** command on the two lines, *EVERY LINE IS DIFFERENT*. I need the byte sequence of the files to be the same because I'm submitting the file as an assignment.

Here is the bare bone of the code I have (borrowed from here and there):

```
from csv import DictReader,DictWriter

class DictWriterEx(DictWriter):
    def writeheader(self):
        header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
        self.writerow(header)

with open('input.csv','rb',) as f:
    dr = DictReader(f)
    with open('output.csv','wb') as o:
        dw = DictWriterEx(o,fieldnames=dr.fieldnames)
        dw.writeheader()
        for row in dr:
            dw.writerow(dict((k, v) for k, v in row.iteritems()))
```

I've also tried changing the

```
dw.writerow(dict((k, v) for k, v in row.iteritems()))
```

line into

```
dw.writerow(dict((k, v.encode('utf-8')) for k, v in row.iteritems()))
```

which gives me the exception:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Please help me solve this issue because I am going crazy.

**Solution:**  Initialize the **DictWriter** with **lineterminator="/n"**

Comment: The line you say you "changed" is identical to what you changed it from.  What was it supposed to be?

Comment: Can you pastebin an example of input and output that is handled improperly?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have added the solution above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible the files have different line endings?  The file you pass to `csv.reader` or `csv.writer` should be opened in binary mode (see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader)), which it doesn't look like you're doing.  This could lead to incorrect line-end characters being written.

Comment: I looked at the files in a hex editor and saw that the line endings were 0A for one file and 0D 0A for the other. Now to test it out and thank you for reminding me

Comment: I tried it with 'b' flag and that didnt solve the issue (But I should have done it anyway). The problem was that the line terminator was \r\n where I just wanted \n. Thank you